# Why isn't Visual Studio Publish naming my assembly correctly?

Tags: asp.net, dll, visual-studio-2013, publish, precompile

I have a WebSite type project that I have converted to a WebApplication type project. With the WebSite project, I used a Web Deployment Project to compile everything into a single DLL. Now I want to use the Visual Studio 2013 Publish feature to accomplish more or less the same thing.

In the Publish settings, I selected a File System connection, so that it publishes to a directory on my computer, and then I FTP the files I need to the server.

I also selected "Precompile during publishing". For the precompile settings, I selected the following: "Allow precompiled site to be updatable", and "Merge all pages and control outputs to a single assembly". For the name of the assembly, I entered "blah.dll" (let's say).

When it deploys the project, though, the name of the DLL is not blah.dll, but blahWebApp.dll -- the name of the project, in other words (which is blahWebApp).

Currently, the name of the application dll on the website is blah.dll. If I replace it with blahWebApp.dll, will ASP.NET know that this is the application dll? There are other DLLs in the bin directory -- one for CuteEditor, another for Captcha, etc.

Which raises the question: how does ASP.NET know which dll it's supposed to run? I don't specify the name in the web.config, and there is no other configuration file that is uploaded to the remote server. (This is a shared server on a hosting company, by the way, so I have no access to IIS or any server settings.)

In any case, if Publish would obey my command and output the correct dll name, that question would be moot. If I simply rename blahWebApp.dll to blah.dll, would this cause any problems?